# Are there natural language paradigms like they are in programming languages?

Tags: semantics

There exist multiple programming language paradigms. Like Imperative programming, Functional programming, Object-Oriented programming, etc. Each with a different 'focus' or 'worldview'.

Do such paradigms exist in natural languages
or 'they are all of the same sort'?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Any difference between natural and programming languages?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/8612/any-difference-between-natural-and-programming-languages)

Comment: Interesting link. What it tells me is that programming languages and natural languages are different things and comparisons between the two are not adequate. But It doesn't really answer the question whether natural languages possess paradigms something akin to programming language paradigms. However someone could ask what do I mean by paradigm anyway? Let's say that it's a strong focus on some language component such as nouns or werbs as compared to other natural languages. Or a language where some component is absent. With a cluster of similar languages near the base language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an entire field of study called [Linguistic typology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_typology) which classifies languages according to various criteria. One or more of the divisions described there may be viewed as analogous to the paradigmatic classification of programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the [Alignment of case marking](https://wals.info/chapter/98) with several systems *neutral*, *nominative-accusative*, *ergative-absolutive*, *active-inactive*, and *tripartite* can be compared to the different paradigms in programming languages. All languages can still express the same things (comparable to being Turing-complete in programming languages) but their viewpoints are quite different.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It's a bit two complicated for me, will require more reading on my part.